# Facebook Graph Api scope is overwritten codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to post on the facebook wall of the user using FacebookConnect but the method createOauth2() method is overriding the scope by the its own permissions.

**EDIT**

> ```
> if (fb.isNativeLoginSupported()) {
>                         Dialog.show("native", "Yes", "Ok", null);
>                         if (!fb.hasPublishPermissions()) {
>                             Dialog.show("permission", " no publish permission", "ok", null);
>                             fb.askPublishPermissions(new LoginCallback() {
>                                 @Override
>                                 public void loginSuccessful() {
>                                     Dialog.show("permission", "accessed: " + fb.hasPublishPermissions(), "Ok", null);
>                                     System.out.println("permission: " + fb.hasPublishPermissions());
>                                     token = fb.getAccessToken().getToken();
>                                     PhotoShare share = new PhotoShare();
>                                     share.sendPhoto(token, id);
>                                 }
>                                 @Override
>                                 public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
>                                     System.out.println("failed permission: " + errorMessage);
>                                     Dialog.show("permission error", errorMessage, "Ok", null);
>                                 }
>                             });
>                         } else {
>                             Dialog.show("permission", "publish permission", "ok", null);
>                             PhotoShare share = new PhotoShare();
>                             share.sendPhoto(token, id);
>                         }
>                     } else {
>                         Dialog.show("permission", "No native support", "Ok", null);
>                         fb.setScope("publish_actions");
>                         fb.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
>                             @Override
>                             public void loginSuccessful() {
>                                 token = fb.getAccessToken().getToken();
>                                 PhotoShare share = new PhotoShare ();
>                                 share.sendPhoto(token, id);
>                             }
>                         });
>                         fb.doLogin();
>                     }
> ```

The Logincall back of `askPublishPermissions` never gets called on the android device.
Also when login the app ask for permissions of friendlist and email which I never asked. In the source code of FacebookConnect the `createOuth()` method is adding them in scope but I dont need those permissions.

**Solution:**

These are the steps I followed for anyone with same problem.
First I found problem with the emulator asking permission. So I created my own Outh login asking the permission.

For the android build.

1. Add the build hint `android.facebook_permissions` key with value the permissions you want. This is a must step. Only include read permission here and not the `publish_action` permission or other write permissions. If you need no permission other than write permission add `public_profile` which is the default permission of facebook.
2. Use `FacebookConenct.askPublishPermissions` for the `publish_actions` permission.
3. If you use `doLogin()` first then for some reason `askPublishPermission` did nothing in my case. So i used `askPublishPermission` without calling `doLogin()` which automatically called the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you request permissions?

Did you notice that you need to call [askPublishPermissions](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/social/FacebookConnect.html#askPublishPermissions-com.codename1.social.LoginCallback-) to write?

Unlike a web application a native application needs to ask for write permissions.

Did you set the build hint `android.facebook_permissions` as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html)?

Comment: I added some details to my answer.

Comment: android.facebook_permissions and some other things solved the problem which i will update in my question. But I still think there is problem for emulator as in login only override the scope of mine. Kindly check facebookConnect.createOuth() method.

Comment: The simulator uses a completely different system (web login) from the device (native login)